# Using Random Forest for Optimisation

Tags: optimization, random-forest

Can random forests be used for optimisation?

I created a random forest which predicts prices, customers will pay. Lets assume I want to maximize the price a customer will pay. To do this I have 3 variables. Two of them are fixed, so you can just modify one variable.

Is it sensible to plot a graph, which shows how price will change depending on values of the third variable?

I don't know a paper in which this has already been done. Are there any arguments against doing this?

Thanks!

Edit: Pseudo-Code for maximizing prices for a customer of age 25 and an income of 20000 USD

```
y = price //dependent variable
X = independent varianbles //in this case customer_age, annual_income, marketing_incentives (only marketing_incentives can be adjusted)
RF = fit random Forest

custAge = 25
annualIncome = 20000
for incentives in range(0,100):
     pricePredcited = RF.predict(custAge, annualIncome, incentives)
     print(pricePredcited)
```

Then just search for the max. pricePredcited

Comment: How will your optimization algorithm look like? Pseudo code would be nice.

Comment: I edited my post accordingly

Comment: I think it's called partial dependence plot

Comment: What you are after is called causal inference: what would have happened if the input was X ( when it was actually Y). Essentially, the problem is that in order to actually do this you need to ab test the prices.just collecting data  ( observational) rather than in  experiments, means that the impact will be confused with correlation to the other variables